# Get notification about invalid views

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, view, event-notification, integration

I have 40 views that are [integrated/synced](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mam.inswas.doc/install/t_ccmdb_postinstalljmsqueues.html) to a work order management system on a weekly basis.

The views are based on GIS tables which are *notoriously messy*. Over time, the views can end up becoming **invalid**.

Example:

- A user deletes or renames a column in an underlying table, but fails to notify I.T. of the change, so the view is not updated accordingly.
- As a result, the view would become invalid: `ORA-04063: view "ROADS_VW" has errors` or `ORA-00904: "FIELD1": invalid identifier`.

---

I would like to catch & fix invalid views (or fix the underlying data) before the views are synced to the work order management system each week.

**Is there a way to get Oracle to notify me about invalid views?**

For instance, if the integrations occur on Fridays, then get an email on Thursdays if any of the views are invalid.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile a view"? And what are the symptoms of "failing to compile"?

Comment: @mustaccio As a novice, I thought that compile meant to select from a view. But it sounds like that was wrong. I'll edit the question.

Comment: In computer science, and IT in general, "to compile" commonly means "to convert a program from a human readable source form into machine-executable code". And it still isn't clear what is meant by "views have errors". Can you give an example of such an error?

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for your patience. I provided some examples in the question.

Comment: It is not a matter of GIS world if users change table/view structures. It only depends on internal processes and privileges. It is really strange if people changes their tables but you can't create primary keys, triggers, unique indexes, etc - this does not match.

Comment: @mustaccio it's also valid to consider compiling "does this code make sense". I frequently use that as a colloquial phrase when dealing with scripting languages (I work in PowerShell a lot, as well as TSQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get invalid views with a procedure like this:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR InvaliViews AS
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME
    FROM USER_OBJECTS
    WHERE object_type = 'VIEW'
        AND status = 'INVALID';

BEGIN

    FOR aView IN InvaliViews LOOP
        UTL_MAIL.SEND(
            sender => 'noreply@your_domain.com',
            recipients => 'your-email@your_domain.com',
            subject => 'Notification about invalid views',
            message => 'View '||aView.OBJECT_NAME||' is not valid');
    end loop;

end;
```

You can run such procedure once a week triggered by [Scheduler Job](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235)